# NAudio - How do I play an audio right after end without any delay?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

This is my simple code

```
var reader = new Mp3FileReader("Audio/Battle Wild Intro.mp3");
var reader2 = new Mp3FileReader("Audio/Battle Wild Loop.mp3");
var waveOut = new DirectSoundOut(); // or WaveOutEvent()
var waveOut2 = new DirectSoundOut();
waveOut.Init(reader);
waveOut2.Init(reader2);
waveOut.Play();
while (waveOut.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped) ;
waveOut2.Play();
```

It's basically a thread? that play the audio until it end, then play an other one... It's working, but there is like a 0.1 sec delay before the next one play.

What I want to do is to play a battle intro, then once the intro is done, start the music loop. Basically like in Pokémon :3 (ex : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQrmCB4ZGGo)

I'm kinda new with threading, your help would be very appreciated ! ^^

Also, if I could do it in Midi instead of mp3/wav with a custom SF, it would be awesome :D

Comment: Is this a winforms application or a console application?

Comment: If you are trying to do this in a console application, I suggest you put your audio files location in a list and play from that list. like in this example: https://gist.github.com/osbornm/4431513

Comment: So I tried your solution, but the delay is still the same :c

Comment: Maybe figure out when the playhead is towards to end of the first file through a time, and then start the next file at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but what I would do instead is concatenate the playlist into one mp3 file, and play that mp3 file instead. When playing a song one after the other, there is a millisecond pause because the next song is loading.

First, make a new class file name called `LoopStream.cs` and put this code in there:

```
public class LoopStream : WaveStream
{
    WaveStream sourceStream;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Loop stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceStream">The stream to read from. Note: the Read method of this stream should return 0 when it reaches the end
    /// or else we will not loop to the start again.</param>
    public LoopStream(WaveStream sourceStream)
    {
        this.sourceStream = sourceStream;
        this.EnableLooping = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this to turn looping on or off
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableLooping { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return source stream's wave format
    /// </summary>
    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return sourceStream.WaveFormat; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoopStream simply returns
    /// </summary>
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Length; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoopStream simply passes on positioning to source stream
    /// </summary>
    public override long Position
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Position; }
        set { sourceStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while (totalBytesRead < count)
        {
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset + totalBytesRead, count - totalBytesRead);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                if (sourceStream.Position == 0 || !EnableLooping)
                {
                    // something wrong with the source stream
                    break;
                }
                // loop
                sourceStream.Position = 0;
            }
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        }
        return totalBytesRead;
    }
}
```

Then this is you main `Program.cs`, to loop through the mp3 file, we will use the `LoopStream` class to loop the mp3 file:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var playlist = new List<string>{ @"c:\Users\User\Music\sound1.mp3",
            @"c:\Users\User\Music\sound2.mp3" };

        var mp3OutputFile = File.Create(@"c:\Users\User\Music\soundnew3.mp3");

        Concatenate(playlist, mp3OutputFile);
        mp3OutputFile.Close();

        var combinedList = new List<string> { @"c:\Users\User\Music\soundnew3.mp3" };

        var playr = new playr(combinedList);
        playr.PlaySong();

        Console.WriteLine("Playing your songs..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Concatenate(List<string> mp3FileNames, Stream output)
    {
        foreach (string file in mp3FileNames)
        {
            Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(file);
            if ((output.Position == 0) && (reader.Id3v2Tag != null))
            {
                output.Write(reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData,
                             0,
                             reader.Id3v2Tag.RawData.Length);
            }
            Mp3Frame frame;
            while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
            {
                output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }
        }
    }        

    public class playr
    {
        private Queue<string> playlist;
        private IWavePlayer player;
        private WaveStream fileWaveStream;

        public playr(List<string> startingPlaylist)
        {
            playlist = new Queue<string>(startingPlaylist);
        }

        public void PlaySong()
        {
            if (fileWaveStream != null)
            {
                fileWaveStream.Dispose();
            }

            if (playlist.Count < 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (player != null && player.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                player.Stop();
            }

            if (player != null)
            {
                player.Dispose();
                player = null;
            }


            player = new WaveOutEvent();

            fileWaveStream = new AudioFileReader(playlist.Dequeue());
            LoopStream loop = new LoopStream(fileWaveStream);
            player.Init(loop);                
            player.PlaybackStopped += (sender, evn) => { PlaySong(); };
            player.Play();

        }
    }
```

If you want to merge WAV files, you can do it like this:

```
public static void Concatenate(List<string> sourceFiles)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = null;
        string outputFile = @"c:\Users\User\Music\soundnew3.wav";

        try
        {
            foreach (string sourceFile in sourceFiles)
            {
                using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile))
                {
                    if (waveFileWriter == null)
                    {
                        // first time in create new Writer
                        waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFile, reader.WaveFormat);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!reader.WaveFormat.Equals(waveFileWriter.WaveFormat))
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't concatenate WAV Files that don't share the same format");
                        }
                    }

                    int read;
                    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        waveFileWriter.WriteData(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (waveFileWriter != null)
            {
                waveFileWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Merging the audio is a great idea :3 but it doesn't help with my problem, because I want an intro and a loop. Once the intro is over, loop for ever the other .mp3/wav/ogg   I wish I could have something as easy as "player.RepositionTime(int milliseconds);"

Comment: I updated to make a loop for the mp3 file. The `LoopStream` constructor class does allow a List, but as far as testing, it will only read the first file and loop that file. This is the solution that I will give, but perhaps someone else could chime in and have a better solution.

Comment: So, I tried your solution, and there is still this annoying 0.05 sec glitch sounds between the two audio >~< the loopstream is working super fine tho ^^ I also decided to use vorbis file instead of the mp3 because the way mp3 files are compressed doesn't make them good for looping with no interruption. I made a small video showing my application and around the end, you will hear a small 'bak' (around 31 sec). When I loop it, we can also hear this 'bak' sound right when it's starting again https://youtu.be/70NV_S8eslE

Comment: I updated the code one more time to fix the audio glitch. The problem was that to merge an mp3 file, there is a specific way to merge and merging it with binary causes this glitch.

Comment: No glitchy sound :3 but it loop the combined file :c like the intro that is supposed to be only played once will loop again